# Exception: Command 'command' was unsuccessful for 4 tries. Latest response: 'command'

Tags: python, dji-sdk, tello-drone

I've created this simple tello code:

```
from djitellopy import Tello
tello = Tello()

tello.connect()
tello.takeoff()

tello.move_left(100)
tello.rotate_clockwise(90)
tello.move_forward(100)

tello.land()
```

However, every time I try to run the code, the drone light is yellow, even when I've connected to its wifi and I get this error:

Exception: Command 'command' was unsuccessful for 4 tries. Latest response:     'command'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Then I connected the app and there was a need to activate the drone through the app. After that, I could connect the PC to the drone and take off / land.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to first connect to the app, I took off and landed with the ryze tello app, then tried the code again and it worked straight away.

Comment: @Towvis and avoid to write an answer sounding like a question, specially ending with a question mark, also avoid the phrase *I have had the same problem* or similar

Comment: Thank you all for the tips. It is my first answer, so I will make sure to heed all advice for the next time. thank you @Tomerikoo for the edit, that reads a lot better.